# Selenium and c# concepts

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-rc

I am new to c-sharp. I was asked to retrieve the selenium commands which are present in the html in c#. I mean to say if we type username as 
UserName: testUser
we get in selenium IDE as

```
command=type
target = xpath="/html..blah blah"
value= testUser
```

Now I have got this information in my C# as I used C# and HTML Parsing. Now I want to execute this in the form of switch.

```
switch(command)
{
  case "type":
             selenium.Type(target,value);
              break;
            // and so on..
    case "click":
         ...........
         break;



 }
```

So in this do I need delegates or some concepts of C# to dynamically execute commands ?
Please reply. I am new to c#.
I hope my question is  clear.

Comment: do you just need to import selenium test cases in C#? I'm not clear what you are asking in the switch statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Selenium-C#-Client](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) which does all that work for you and you can generate test classes automatically with Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Using C# with selenium you can do actions on webpage and verify the information on the webpage by retrieving text values etc.

On How to setup selenium with C# and creating basic script, you can refer below to webpages

[How to setup C#,nUnit and selenium client drivers on VSExpress for Automated tests](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/how-to-setup-cnunit-and-selenium-client.html?utm_source=BP_recent)

[Creating Basic Selenium web driver test case using Nunit and C#](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/creating-basic-selenium-web-driver-test.html)